# AWS RDS db.r5.large instance with 100GB GP2 volume limited to ~40 read IOPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql

We just restored a snapshot of one of our Postgres databases in RDS. The instance used to be a db.t2.xlarge, and we turned it into a db.r5.large. It has a GP2 SSD volume of 100GB.

r5.large instances are supposed to be "EBS optimized", yet I'm having a surprisingly low read IOPS, as shown in the graph below.

[image: Average READ IOPS graph, showing a spike at 40]

This is the result of a `SELECT COUNT(*)` on a large table. For the same query, our t2.xlarge instance has no trouble reaching 1250 IOPS. There doesn't seem to be any bottleneck elsewhere: the CPU is roughly at 0%, and there's plenty of memory available.

Furthermore, the AWS documentation seems to indicate that I could expect at least 300 IOPS for a volume that size:

> GP2 is designed to offer single-digit millisecond latencies, deliver a consistent baseline performance of 3 IOPS/GB (minimum 100 IOPS) to a maximum of 16,000 IOPS

(see https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/features/)

Why is the r5.large so slow?

Comment: With EC2, when snapshots are restored blocks are streamed in from S3 when required. I suspect the same is true for RDS. So you get a lot of latency when you start using a database based on a snapshot as data is bought from S3 to EBS / local disk, but once the data is stored locally performance goes up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the IOPS are back to reasonable values now. It could be related to IO credits or the snapshot still being restored... not sure.

[image: Read IOPS is back to normal]

Answer (score -1):

IOPS depend on disk size, if you increase the disk size the available IOPS will increase as well.

Comment: Yes, as is explained in the quote, I should have at least 300 IOPS with my 100GB volume.